# Как работает поиск в массиве mongoDB через Spring jpa?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-jpa

Есть такой пару тысяч объектов по типу такого:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5ffbfca73fb224209c6d27be"),
  "activeStates" : ["logicConnectionLost", ...],
  ...,
  "_class" : "Entity"
}
```

Мне нужно посчитать количество объектов у которых массив **activeStates** содержит хотя бы один элемент из входящего массива

Я использую метод репозитория
**countByActiveStatesIn(Set states);**

Сравнивает ли Монго каждый с каждым до конца всех массивов или же пока не найдет первое соответствие? Входящий массив может быть достаточно большим из-за чего запрос к БД может быть 1000-1500мс. Можно ли как-то быстрее посчитать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ускорить можно с помощью индексации, но надо учитывать, что индексированные поля будут где-то храниться и сколько-то занимать памяти.

Можно проиндексировать в классе через аннотацию `@Index`, либо через MongoDB

```
db.collectionName.createIndex({"fieldName" : 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте получать записи пэйдженированно с помощью метода findAll(Pageble pageble),
соответственно в размере страницы, при запросе, указывать необходимое количество элементов (например 100) и с каждой итерацией через StreamApi проверять массив внутри объектов

Comment: Достаточно сомнительное решение, получать целый объект. Потому что тут не только просадка по производительности будет (из-за преобразования объекта. Вдруг у него 100 полей), но и просадка по памяти. Да и find в mongoDB работает дольше чем countDocuments